# SELECT INTO syntax for Snowflake Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, insert-into, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I believe there's an `SELECT INTO`-like syntax in Snowflake, but I am unable to find documentation or examples to use it.

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
    Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    Date DATE NOT NULL, 
    UserID STRING,
    Address STRING,
    Phone STRING,
    Value INTEGER
);

COPY INTO raw_data from 's3://my_bucket'
CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='XXXXX' AWS_SECRET_KEY='XXXX')
ON_ERROR=CONTINUE;

CREATE TABLE summary (
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    UserID STRING,
    Value INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO summary 
SELECT Date, UserID, Value FROM raw_data
```

The above works, but rather than defining the table `summary` I want to `SELECT INTO` and have the SQL parser create the table for me.

Comment: `create table summary as select ...` would be standard SQL

Comment: Wow. That's a really documentation-free website they've got there, isn't it?

Comment: @MattGibson There's documentation inside the tool. I think they are only recently beginning to open up to a larger customer base.

Answer (score 29):

You can use Create Table AS (CTAS) to accomplish this. In your case it would be:

```
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY AS
SELECT
  Date
, UserID
, Value
FROM
  raw_data;
```

Here is an example using no data that I have tested:

```
create table foo as select $1, $2
from

    values ( 1, 'two' ), ( 3, 'four' ), ( 5, 'six' );

    select * from foo;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE  summary 
AS
SELECT Date, UserID, Value 
FROM raw_data

Answer (score -4):

You can also use the standard "WITH AS" nomenclature:

```
    with a as (
        SELECT
        Date
        ,UserID
        ,Value
        FROM
        raw_data)
    SELECT * FROM a
```

Comment: Will give you a CTE.

Comment: You are right...now I see why people are voting it down :)